# I want to copy the contents of the shapes in visio

Tags: visio

hope you can help. I have a visio file will a lot of shapes (100s) I want to copy the contents of the shapes (the words) and paste it into a spreadsheet. I can't figure out if this is possible. Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You mean text in shapes ?
2. These shapes are groups or single shapes ?

Answer (score 0):

That code iterate single shapes in page and fill workbook rows

```
Sub vv()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ea As Object
    ' create new excel session
    Set ea = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ' make new excel session visible
    ea.Visible = True
    Dim ew As Object
    ' create new workbook
    Set ew = ea.workbooks.Add
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 0
    ' iterate all shapes in active page
    For Each sh In ActivePage.Shapes
    ' if shape have some text add content to workbook
    If Len(sh.Text) > 0 Then
    r = r + 1
    ew.sheets(1).Cells(r, 1) = sh.Text
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a report to export the text of the shapes.
http://www.hamishking.com/2010/05/27/using-visio-shape-reports-to-export-detail-from-your-diagrams/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for  your responses. I ran a report to export the text of the shapes as someone suggested at it worked. ty